# How to make Ruby time-out a HTTP request after X time elapsed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant

I am trying to detect if a Vagrant host is connected locally to the network I need to access.  If not, I want to require and configure a proxy so that I can download some internal resources required to build the project.

How do I make a HTTP request that times out after a given number of seconds regardless of success or failure?

I would expect the following code to return 1 or 2 seconds for the time elapsed:

```
HTTP_NETWORK_TEST_HOST = '172.16.0.1'

start1 = Time.now
begin
    http = Net::HTTP.new(HTTP_NETWORK_TEST_HOST, '80')
    http.read_timeout = 2
    http.open_timeout = 2
    response = http.start do |http|
        http.get('/')
    end
    NETWORK_PROXY_NEEDED = false
rescue Timeout::Error => e
    NETWORK_PROXY_NEEDED = true
end
finish1 = Time.now

start2 = Time.now
begin
    Timeout::timeout(1) {
        http = Net::HTTP.new(HTTP_NETWORK_TEST_HOST, '80')
        response = http.start do |http|
            http.get('/')
        end
    }
    NETWORK_PROXY_NEEDED = false
rescue
    NETWORK_PROXY_NEEDED = true
end
finish2 = Time.now


start3 = Time.now
begin
    http = Net::HTTP.start(HTTP_NETWORK_TEST_HOST, '80', {read_timeout: 5, open_timeout: 5})
    response =  http.get('/')
    NETWORK_PROXY_NEEDED = false
rescue Timeout::Error => e
    NETWORK_PROXY_NEEDED = true
end
finish3 = Time.now


puts 'time 1'
puts finish1 - start1

puts 'time 2'
puts finish2 - start2

puts 'time 3'
puts finish3 - start3
```

Results in:

```
time 1
21.003133
time 2
21.012332
time 3
21.009758
```

**Answer was provided to me by al2o3-cr on #ruby at freenode irc:**

https://gist.github.com/gr33n7007h/d041f4fbc08f0e065854bb180330c3ac

```
NETWORK_PROXY_NEEDED = 
begin
  Socket.tcp(TEST_HOST, 80, connect_timeout: 1)&.close
  false
rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT
  true
end
```

Comment: Please don't summarize answers in your question. The question is for just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer was provided to me by al2o3-cr on #ruby at freenode irc:**

https://gist.github.com/gr33n7007h/d041f4fbc08f0e065854bb180330c3ac

```
NETWORK_PROXY_NEEDED = 
begin
  Socket.tcp(TEST_HOST, 80, connect_timeout: 1)&.close
  false
rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT
  true
end
```